# Resizing object or alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, whmcs

I am trying to implement whmcs in my main website, I started with an Iframe but it has his issues in google chrome. 
Now I am experimenting with the object tag. this works like a charm but I need to find a way to resize the object with the content.

For example when a user searches for a domain name the page its height changes with a list for all available domains.

I searched the web for a solution and came around some javascript, but nothing seems to work only a fixed height.

Is there an alternative or a solution for this?

thx in advance!

Comment: Use `calc()` to resize an object, for example: `height: calc(100% - 0px);` sets the height to 100%.

Comment: That did not work, it sets the height, but when the content changes it doesn't resize.